# Private Method for Nested Resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

From Previous:

[Rails 4 Nested Resources/Routes... almost there...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444402/rails-4-nested-resources-routes-almost-there/22444516?noredirect=1#comment34136080_22444516)

My private method within my lines controller to load the manufacturer into the controller is throwing an error...

I use before_filter :load_manufacturer

and the function is:

```
def load_manufacturer
  @manufacturer = Manufacturer.find(params[:manufacturer_id])
end
```

When I try to edit the line instance in the form, I get:

```
Couldn't find Manufacturer with id=manufacturer_id
```

But it is passing the manufcaturer params ok...

```
Parameters:

{"manufacturer_id"=>"manufacturer_id",
 "id"=>"17"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your manufacturer id is incorrectly set. Its set to string `"manufacturer_id"` instead of an integer id value(in String format). The problem lies else where. As you can see

`{"manufacturer_id"=>"manufacturer_id"`

Should look something like

`{"manufacturer_id"=>"1"`

manufacturer_id should be an integer value

Comment: Crap. Thanks. I couldn't believe it. But you're right, my schema is messed up.

Comment: I fixed this by rolling back the DB then changing type to string. But now I'm getting :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463193/private-method-to-load-parent-resource-failing